# Talend ETL Converting Excel to JSON

Tags: json, talend

I would like to convert below Excel  to JSON Format. Could you please help

[image]

Required JSON Format

[
{
"name": "Basil",
"id": 1,
"report": [
{
"subject": "Maths",
"exams": [
{
"semister": 1,
"mark": 20
},
{
"semister": 2,
"mark": 21
},
{
"semister": 3,
"mark": 22
}
]
},
{
"subject": "Physics",
"exams": [
{
"semister": 1,
"mark": 41
},
{
"semister": 2,
"mark": 44
},
{
"semister": 3,
"mark": 45
}
]
}
]
}
]

Answer (score 0):

- Save your "required JSON Format" as a json example file.
- In talend, go to "Metadata" section (in repository) , then "Create JSON File".
- Select "output schema" , then select your example file as a source file.
- Check the mapping proposed by Talend, add Loops (on exam i think)
- When done, use a tWriteJsonField component with your freshly created metadata as an output, input should be your tFileInputExcel --> tMap.
- Map columns from your excel file to your output in tMap